# How to generate simple_form views using HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, simple-form

I'm learning HAML and using twitter bootstrap and simple_form. When I run for example this code

```
rails g scaffold product name --no-stylesheets
rake db:migrate
rails g bootstrap:themed products -f
```

it generates few erb-views.

Is there a way to generate haml-views instead of erb using simple_form generator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

include in your gemfile
    `gem "haml-rails"`
it will set default view format to haml